# UITableView unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift

I'm confused on what is going on I'm doing a tutorial on collection views as I'm fairly new to programming, and I believe I'm doing everything right but I get hit `-[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

Here is the tutorial:
http://www.thorntech.com/2015/08/want-your-swift-app-to-scroll-in-two-directions-like-netflix-heres-how/

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

var categories = ["Action", "Drama", "Science Fiction", "Kids", "Horror"]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return categories[section]
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return categories.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CategoryRow
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Have you set Tableview delegate to UITableViewDataSource using storyboard or programmtically.?**

set Tableview delegate to **UITableViewDataSource programmtically.**

```
yourtableview.dataSource=self
```

**or**

using storyboard set **Tableview delegate to UITableViewDataSource** show below image.

[image]

Or

**check if you set UITableViewDataSource wrong to any other view.**

Comment: It worked! Thanks I set my datasource to the tableview directly instead of the viewcontroller

Comment: I actually had a problem were I set it both programmatically and in the storyboard and it gave me and error (I forgot that i deleted the view and then created it agin). Make sure to only do one strategy, not both.